# Order of controls in layout changed when site was updated from Sitecore 7.5 to 9.3

Tags: presentation, upgrade

After upgrading our Sitecore site from 7.5 to 9.3 we discovered that the order of controls in layouts for some items has changed. Therefore the actual layout of the pages also changed.
There seems to be no pattern to how the order changed - it just seems "scrambled".

We found this article from Sitecore's knowledge base that describes a problem that sounds more or less like our problem: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/672981
However, the solution did not work (the order of the controls is still wrong).
Could there be any other reason for this problem? (they refer to a "related issue" in the article) 
Or could it be that the problem is the same as the one described in the article, but that something else is required to fix it?
Could it be something that happened during migration (we used Express Migration Tool for the migration of data)?

[image: Layout details - The order of the controls was different in 7.5]

Comment: Are you simply seeing that the order is reversed for all the components?

Comment: @Michael West - no, not reversed. There is no apparent pattern to the order.